# How do I properly 'Retweet with a comment' via Twitter's API

Tags: twitter

Twitter has recently implemented an automatic way of quoting tweets. It basically extracts an url from a tweet and shows it embedded within your tweet.

My problem is: **how do I 'retweet with a comment' without showing the original tweet URL via API?**

Retweeting from the website makes the RT look like this [image].

But when I'm manually prepending a tweet url to my tweet, it looks like this [image].

notice the literal url.

Answer (score 6):

your tweet has a quoted_status, just put the tweet url as attachment_url args, e.g.

`client.update('cool', attachment_url: 'https://twitter.com/emorima/status/1061581991798169600')`

it's ruby code with twitter gem

Answer (score 5):

My understanding is that you are achieving the closest solution that Twitter API offers. [This thread](https://twittercommunity.com/t/method-to-retweet-with-comment/35330/11) talks about doing the following:

1. do a [status update](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update), with the 'status' field containing the text of the original tweet, followed by the link to the original tweet. The 'in_reply_to_status_id' field should not be set. This action does not result in the "retweet count" being increased.
2. [do a retweet](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/retweet/%3Aid), which will increase the [retweet count](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/retweeters/ids).

Comment: The Twitter API can do what you can do with the web or first-party apps, i.e. quote-tweeting without the URL showing up. See the answer by @lfx_cool

Answer (score 1):

Based on lfx_cool's answer, I was able to achieve it with this:
[statuses/update](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update)

```
post('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json', {
status:'Some comment', attachment_url:`https://twitter.com/${user.screen_name}/status/${id_str}`,
});
```